# How to go back a few commits, but still keep commit history in git?

Tags: git, reset

This has been sort of asked before, but not exactly.

Here is what I want to know.

Suppose I have git repository with the following commits:

```
$ git log
commit4
commit3
commit2
commit1
```

I now realize that I need to get commit 1 back into my workspace and "start over". I can do this:

```
$ git reset --hard commit1
```

This will accomplish what I want, but if I go and look at the log again:

```
$ git log
commit1
```

Only the first commit is showing up. What I really want to see is this:

```
$ git log
commit5-same-as-commit1
commit4
commit3
commit2
commit1
```

I am coming from subversion and if I wanted to accomplish this in subversion, it would be quite easy. Just check out a particular previous revision to your local workspace and then commit. Now, you have all the previous revisions, plus the new one.

How do I accomplish this in git?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "start over"? Do you mean to create a new branch off of commit1 and create new commits from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be other ways but this is one.

```
git revert -n commit4 commit3 commit2 commit1
```

will get your working tree (and index) back to the state at `commit 1`. After that, `git commit` will create a new commit on top of `commit 4` which will change your tree to back to what it was at `commit 1`.

Answer (score 2):

As a DVCS, Git doesn't enforce a linear line of development, but rather a directed graph. Here's what I would do, given that you want to save the other commits:

```
$ git branch feature-I-was-working-on commit4
```

This creates a branch titled `feature-I-was-working-on`, and points it at `commit4`. This way, you can put this branch aside and come back to it later.

```
$ git checkout commit1
```

This makes your working files the same as they were after `commit1` was committed.

```
$ git checkout -b feature-Im-now-working-on
```

This creates a new branch titled `feature-Im-now-working-on`, and points it at the current commit you're on (if you've been following along, that's `commit1`).

So now if you `git checkout feature-Im-now-working-on`, you don't get any of `commit2`, `commit3`, or `commit4`. If you check out `feature-I-was-working-on`, you get those.

Now, you're on the branch `feature-Im-now-working-on`, and you make more commits. Those commits don't get into `feature-I-was-working-on`, but you can go back to it at any time.

But let's say that now you want to get `commit2`, `commit3`, and `commit4` into `feature-Im-now-working-on`. That's simple! First check out `feature-Im-now-working-on`, then run this command:

```
$ git merge feature-I-was-working-on
```

DVCSs are more complicated than Subversion, but they're also more powerful. If you work with them and not against them, they let you easily do things you would never think of in Subversion.